# VBA - "Incompatible Types Error" that is madness

Tags: vba, textbox

My problem is so simple that it's ridiculous...

If I create a Module like:

```
Sub Check_TextBox(ByVal CheckThisBox As TextBox)
'With anything. Even if I leave this blank..
End sub
```

And try to call it on a UserForm like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Check_TextBox(Me.TextBox1)
End Sub
```

It simply gives me "Incompatible Types Error"... I have no clue about what's going on. "TextBox1" **IS** a TextBox and I declare it as one on the Sub.

Comment: Me is only available in Classes and Forms. It is not available in Modules.

Answer (score 1):

Need to be a bit more explicit about the parameter type:

```
Sub Check_TextBox(CheckThisBox As msforms.TextBox)
    Debug.Print CheckThisBox.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: That actually worked! Thank very much bro. 
This is funny, because I have the exactly same sub with a ComboBox and worked fine with it. There was no need to use "msforms." before it.